# Find Out What Previous Nameserver Were

Tags: ip, hosting, web-hosting, nameservers

Recently we've had a domain that we've been hosting & we've had an issue where the domains nameservers were changed without us knowing.

Is there a way to find out when the nameservers were changed?

FYI, I've already done many ping tests to try & find out if the previous nameservers still show & it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

These are pretty cool stuff.

- http://whoisrequest.org/history/
- http://dnscheck.iis.se/